# how to speed up my query in oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, performance, select

The query is :

```
SELECT COUNT(CONF_FILE) FROM modem_reference WHERE CONF_FILE like '%example%';
```

It's taking one minute to finish, there are 1402856 lines in this table.

Is there any trick to speed up the query?

PS: I'm not the the database admin.

Comment: have a look at [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html)

Comment: It's hard to tell you more without the table structure, although the select query itself cannot be simplied more than it is you can possibly be reduced by optimizing the table structure, i.e. making sure the table is indexed and so on. Best take a look at some [reading materials](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT total=SUM(mr.CONF_FILE) FROM modem_reference mr WHERE CONF_FILE like '%example%';
```

Comment: dint get you.Are you getting any error when you execute the query?

Comment: yes, i'm getting : ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: SELECT total=SUM(modem_reference.CONF_FILE) FROM modem_reference WHERE CONF_FILE like "%example%";

Comment: Change the tag from [mysql] to [oracle].

Comment: Why would using a non-standard (and invalid for almost every DBMS) way of assigning a column alias change anything for the performance?